# Lefto/recto textblock alignment issue using memoir class

Tags: margins, memoir

I'm trying to produce a 5x8 book for Createspace using the memoir class. My problem is the two text blocks on adjacent pages are far too close to the spine. So much so then when you print a proof the book is almost impossible to read. Below it the minimal latex that reproduces the issue.

```
\documentclass[14pt,english]{memoir}
\usepackage[paperwidth=5in,paperheight=8in]{geometry}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\title{Book Title}
\author{Book Auhor}
\maketitle

\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Here's a sample rendering of the page. As you can see the margins should basically be swapped or the binding in the centre will swallow up the text near to it.

[image]

I've poured over the memoir class manual and tried adjusting various margins but I couldn't get it to sit right.

Comment: What about adding the `twoside` option to the document class?

Comment: the margins in your image look about right (typically the outer ones should be around twice the inner ones) but if you are going to lose space due to binding the geometry package has specific options to set a binding offset

Comment: Ah yes  @DavidCarlisle setting the binding offset in the geometry package instead of the memoir class seems to work `\geometry{bindingoffset=0.375in,textwidth=280pt}`. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The margins in your image look about right (typically the outer ones should be around twice the inner ones) but if you are going to lose space due to binding the geometry package has specific options to set a binding offset

eg

```
\geometry{bindingoffset=0.375in,textwidth=280pt}
```

Comment: The `memoir` class also caters for a binding offset via `\setbinding{length}`